# store.dispatch causes ( NotAllowedError )

Tags: reactjs, redux, dispatch, redux-actions

I have a function in where I load a given users conversations. It has worked fault free until this morning where I started getting this error message

**Unhandled Rejection (NotAllowedError): The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.**

This I my function

```
async function init_chat(){
  let conversations = await api_call_based_on_jwt('/chat/get_user_conversations.php');

  store.dispatch( set_conversations(conversations) ); 

  if(conversations.length > 0){
    store.dispatch( sort_conversations() );
    store.dispatch(set_conversation( find_conversation(conversations, store.getState().chat.conversations[0].conversation_id) ));
  }
}
```

Set conversations

```
export const set_conversations = (conversations) => ({
  type : SET_CONVERSATIONS,
  payload : conversations
});
```

Has any one else came across this problem before?

**The store.dispatch(set_conversations(conversations)) is the one that causes the problem**

Comment: what response are you getting in conversations ? and can you show set_conversations implementation ?

Comment: The response from get_user_conversations is an array of js objects. See set_conversations in updated question

Comment: What's the response from the request that causes the error? Seems like it's not permitted on the server side.

Comment: i dont think so the error is because of store dispatch,